# Is there a way to delete a folder that contains only one specific file with batch?

Tags: batch-file, directory, rmdir

Need a way to delete a folder (rd/rmdir) if it contains only one specific file within. If there are any other files or subfolders, ignore it. Trying to do so with as little code as possible. Currently, I'm doing this...

```
If Exist "C:\Folder\SubFolder\filename.txt" Move /Y "C:\Folder\SubFolder\filename.txt" "%TEMP%"
If Not Exist "C:\Folder\SubFolder\*" RD "C:\Folder\SubFolder" /Q /S
```

However, even though the folder contains no files, the folder is never deleted.

Is this possible within a batch file? Thanx in advance.

Comment: `If Not Exist "C:\Folder\SubFolder\*"` is your problem. You cannot use a wilcard to search for any file like that.

Comment: Could you please clarify the exact task? Is it to identify a directory which contains only one specific file, but no other file or directory objects, and if found, move that file and remove that directory? Is it to locate a directory containing a specific file, move that file, then remove that directory regardless of any other file or directory objects which may remain within it? Or perhaps to identify a directory containing the specific file, and only if that directory becomes empty after moving that file, remove that directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `find` to count the number of files in the directory and then `findstr` to determine the errorlevel and simply use conditional operator `&&`

No need to check if the file exists either, you can redirect stderr to `nul` when the file is not found.

```
@echo off
Move /Y "C:\Folder\SubFolder\filename.txt" "%TEMP%" 2>nul
(dir /b "C:\Folder\SubFolder\*" | find /C /V "^" | findstr /R "\<0\>") && rd /S /Q "C:\Folder\SubFolder"
```

*Edit*

As you mentioned that you now only want to move the file if it is the only file in the directory, a few amendments in the current code sorts that out:

```
@echo off
set "_dir=C:\Folder\SubFolder"
set "fname=filename.txt"

(dir /b "%_dir%\*" | find /C /V "^" | findstr /R "\<1\>" >nul) && if exist "%_dir%\%fname%" (
   move /Y "%_dir%\%fname%" "%temp%"
   rd /S /Q "%_dir%"
)
```

This time, we check to see if there is only 1 item (file or dir) in the folder, if it is, we test to see if it is `filename.txt` if not, then we will skip the code block, if it is, move the file and remove the directory.

I created variables for you as `_dir` and `fname` that way you only update those two fields instead of all over the code.

Comment: This works perfectly! However, now, after moving the file in question to the TEMP folder, if the folder you're checking isn't empty, how do we move the file back? Thanx again.

Comment: Will update the answer.